# Directus api create item works but data values are null

Tags: directus

Using Directus online (https://projectcode.directus.app install of local or server install). I can successfully create item but data I send is always null.

This is happening running my code

```
axios.post( 
    `${endpoint}/items/collection_name`, 
    { data: { "field_name": "testthis" } }, 
    { headers: headers } 
  );
```

And using Postman. Result is always

```
date_created: "2022-05-05T13:55:47"
id: 14
field_name: null
```

I can get items, search and filter with no issue. What am I missing?

ETA: Postman works with graphql and query

```
mutation {
    create_collection_name_item(data: { field_name: "Hello again!" }) {
        field_name
    }
}
```

So why is api getting null values?

ETA 2: Postman api headers

Request

```
Authorization: Bearer the_very_long_token
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 45943ddb-5c60-4d45-8887-a05207f9469e
Host: k2g2xa7b.directus.app
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 13
```

Response

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 135
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Mon, 09 May 2022 14:04:54 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Range
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval';worker-src 'self' blob:;child-src 'self' blob:;img-src 'self' data: blob: https://cdn.directus.io;media-src 'self' https://cdn.directus.io;connect-src 'self' https://*;default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';block-all-mixed-content;font-src 'self' https: data:;frame-ancestors 'self';object-src 'none';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline'
Etag: W/"87-n/ABsgX1O7F1qQ7x0xdJgMV7VDc"
Server: Caddy
Vary: Origin, Cache-Control
X-Powered-By: Directus
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 dcd16c430149132ea12a5783d54ff114.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: YTO50-P2
X-Amz-Cf-Id: Z19onMWqxvINuZ7iMQIJQeSRFrgW12a4gxZtcWPyubaWQCeaUnfLfA==
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What headers do you provide? It seems that `Content-Type` is not determined automatically, so it may be as simple as including `Content-Type: application/json` in your headers.

Comment: Will add Postman request and response headers to original post.

Comment: Hurray! If I change from using Postman Body > x-www-form-urlencoded to Body > raw and add Content-Type: application/json to header it sends data. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like for some reason it defaulted to `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`; glad it works!

Answer (score 0):

in python:

```
import requests, json

token = 'your token'

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': f"Bearer {token}",
}

payload = [
    {
        "title" : "my first item",
    }
]
r= requests.post(
    url = "https://cms.uat.<your subdomain>.com/items/<your collection>",
    data = json.dumps(payload),
    headers = headers
)

print(r.json())
```